# Windows 7 Search Part of Filename

Tags: windows-7, search, windows-search

I'm trying to search for all files that contain the word "box". I get results for files that start with box, such as "box01", "boxcar" etc. But I do not get files that end with or contain the search word, such as "thebox", "thisboxfile".

How can I search for part of a file's name in Windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are using windows explorer. Navigate to the closest portion of the directory tree where you think the file is. Then in the top right search box, use the wildcard syntax, and type "*box".
The asterisk in front of or after, means match anything.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the `name:` prefix.

Comment: Thanks to [cody codes and Jason C](http://superuser.com/questions/774612/search-partial-filenames-in-windows-explorer#774615), I've discovered that `name:~=keyword` as well as `name:~~keyword` do the job in this case.

Comment: Combining this with double quotes, you can search for something with spaces too, like: `name:~="keyword keyword"`

Comment: Microsoft, kings of usability and user friendliness. Even a search box requires declarative programming language knowledge to use. #mustbethistall

Answer (score 5):

[Everything Search](http://www.voidtools.com/download.php) is the best tool I have ever used and its free and much faster than other's, just search whatever you want just enter the word or file name. [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) is another tool which can see through the contents of the files.

[image]

Comment: OMG Everything is amazing!

Comment: @MarcoDemaio, everything *i̲s̲* amazing... lol