# Search partial filenames in windows explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm attempting to search part of a filename in windows explorer, but unless the part of the name I search for is at the very beginning or is separated by spaces or underscores, it fails to match. For example, a file named HelloWorld.java will match a search of `hello`, but not `world`. `*world` fails as well.

Is there a native solution to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 Search Part of Filename](http://superuser.com/questions/408734/windows-7-search-part-of-filename)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using this keyword and searching for "world": `name:~=world` will do the trick.

For more advanced search tips:

- [A guide to using Windows Search](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/a-guide-to-using-windows-search-two-alternatives/b0f4229d-623a-46dd-a84e-94e666bbe505)
- [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! `name:~=world` also works.

Comment: My fingers thank you for checking that `name:~=` also works.

Comment: You rock - I was stuck on this myself and being late on a Saturday was getting ticked off. I rarely use windows search but have to in this case.

Comment: Is there a way to not have the search happening incrementally?

Comment: `filename:*world` also works (Windows7)

Comment: Can you please describe what this answer is doing? There is no indication here of what `~=` is.

Comment: How we can search using a partial match but using the "content:" criteria? I am tried `content:~=world` it is not working. I have to specify the term fully and a partial match doesn't work.

Comment: See the simpler *world* search below.

Comment: I couldn't find any trace of ":~=" in either of  the references that were cited.  Windows search is barely usable because it isn't documented.

Answer (score 5):

`*world*`, the extension is part of what it runs the match against.

With `name:` you can use `~~world`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with the `name:` prefix.

Comment: @Josh What about `~~world`?

Comment: `name:~~world` as well as `name:~=world` both seem to work. Thanks Jason.

Comment: And what is this syntax doing?

Comment: @randy I'd have to look up name option to recall exact behavior but phone is about to die so if I had to guess I'd say ~~ is maybe something like "contains"? Don't quote me on that sorry for forgetting. Prob should've linked to docs ‍♂️.

Answer (score 2):

Try a simple wildcard search `*` So your search would be `*world`

Wildcard search should pull up any partial matches however won't highlight the result in the file name. A lot simpler than typing out the other searches...

Answer (score 0):

I found that (name:~='your name') and (name:~= 'your name') and (filename:* 'your name') would not work form me

BUT I stored file by NUMERALS

However (* your numerical) does- Even for a part match

i.e. file = 123456789 Search (*5678) does the job

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me (search for all files that contain the word 'subaru' and 'v2' in the file name : 
  - System.FileName:~=(*subaru*v2)

Other example (search for all files that contain the word 'subaru' with the extension '.html' :
  - System.FileName:~=(*subaru*.html)

Comment: Add (*) asterisque symbol before and in between word and at end to match the "contain" search

Answer (score 0):

Search for a single word:

```
filename:*world*
```

Search for multiple words:

```
filename:(*hello* *world*)
```

Don't forget the localized keywords, like in German:

```
dateiname:(*hello* *world*)
```

As already mentioned, the `name:` option works as well, but regarding the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx) it is usually a "property" of a file and not the filename itself. So I would say `name:` searches in filename AND metadata of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/)

"Everything" is search engine that locates files and folders by filename instantly for Windows.

Unlike Windows search "Everything" initially displays every file and folder on your computer (hence the name "Everything").

You type in a search filter to limit what files and folders are displayed.